# Новогодний конкурс (с наградой!)

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

Дорогие участники сайта «Русский язык»,

поздравляем вас с наступающим Новым годом! Чтобы отметить это прекрасное событие, предлагаем вам принять участие в конкурсе, победителю которого компания Stack Exchange подарит сувенир (настоящий!).

Вот что нужно сделать:

1. Активно задавайте интересные вопросы в период действия конкурса (см. ниже).
2. Давайте содержательные ответы.
3. Помогайте улучшать сообщения других участников, оставляя полезные комментарии.
4. ***(НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫЙ ПУНКТ)*** Оставьте ответ под этим объявлением, в котором расскажите о своем опыте, приобретенном за время участия в жизни сайта, либо о том, как вы узнали о «Русском языке», либо опишите общие впечатления, которые вы получили, давая ответы и/или оставляя вопросы. Иными словами, напишите что-нибудь о нашем сайте.

Чтобы определить победителя, мы сравним активность всех участников, выполнивших перечисленные выше пункты, и выберем наиболее продуктивного конкурсанта (т. е. того, кто создаст наибольшее количество полезных сообщений). Полезными признаются вопросы и ответы с рейтингом ≧3, а также комментарии с рейтингом ≧2.

> **Подробнее о процедуре выбора победителя:**
>   Рассмотрим ситуацию: есть
>   три участника, борющихся за первое место в конкурсе:
>
> **Участник A**, который создал три вопроса (рейтинг каждого из которых +5), 10 ответов (5 из которых с рейтингом +2, другие — +3), оставил 7 полезных комментариев. Всего 15 полезных сообщений.
>
> **Участник Б**, который создал 10 вопросов (рейтинг каждого из которых +2), 6 ответов (+3), оставил 4 полезных комментариев. Всего 10 полезных сообщений.
>
> **Участник В**, который создал 3 вопроса (рейтинг каждого из которых +8), 3 ответа (+10), оставил 2 полезных комментария. Всего 8 полезных сообщений.
>
> Победителем станет **А**, потому что у него самое большое общее
>   количество полезных сообщений.

Итоги конкурса будут подведены [на Мете](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/) не позднее 1 февраля 2019 года.

Конкурс начинается с сегодняшнего дня (19 декабря 2018 года) и будет завершен 10 января в 23:59 по МСК. Приглашаются ***все*** участники.

*Доставка сувенира будет возможна в страны СНГ, Европы и в США. Прочую информацию просим уточнять в комментариях.*

Comment: Рейтинг ответа определяется разницей плюсов и минусов? Тот факт, что ответ принят, никак не влияет на результат?

Comment: @М_Г рейтинг ответа — это то число, что отображается слева от сообщения; он и учитывается ) Нет, не влияет.

Comment: @Aer! Здесь филологов три с половиной штуки, всё больше какие-то непрофессиональные бегемоты, -  кого о чём спрашивать?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova не понимаю, о чем вы. Уверен, вам отлично знакома тематика сайта.

Comment: А рейтинг вопросов — это число между двумя стрелками слева? Иль как?