# С Рождеством и Новым годом!

Tags: обсуждение, поздравление

Друзья,

поздравляем вас с Рождеством и с Новым годом!

Благодарим вас за участие в развитии нашего сайта, за то, что вы ставите интересные вопросы и даете полезные ответы! Надеемся, что в 2019 году наш ждет много интересного и нового.

Надеемся, что вы уже успели поучаствовать в [новогоднем конкурсе](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/178412); если нет, еще не поздно присоединиться :)

Желаем вам всего доброго в новом году!