# Результаты новогоднего конкурса — 2019

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

Благодарим каждого принявшего участие в [новогоднем конкурсе](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/178412) — 2019!

Мы внимательно посчитали все полезные сообщения (вопросы и ответы с рейтингом ≧3, а также комментарии с рейтингом ≧2), оставленные на сайте с 19 декабря 2018 года по 11 января 2019 года. Вот результаты.

Победителями стали три автора, создавшие в указанный период наибольшее количество полезных сообщений:

- [Sharon](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/180132/sharon) (23 ответа/вопроса, 1 комментарий);
- [Людмила](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/247/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0) (19 ответов/вопросов);
- [М_Г](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/183327/%D0%9C-%D0%93) (9 ответов/вопросов, 1 комментарий).

Поздравляем победителей и благодарим всех участников!

*Информация о том, как получить награду, будет сообщена позже.*

Answer (score 3):

Для меня попасть в победители было тоже совершенной неожиданностью.

Всё дело в том, что я решила, что конкурс будет **общий,** а не для отдела "Русский язык", поэтому шансов у нас, по моему мнению, было немного.

Тем не менее спасибо за доверие, а также **большая благодарность нашим прекрасным модераторам,** которые обеспечивают порядок на сайте и дают нам возможность нормально работать.

И особенная признательность от меня лично за то, что они напомнили мне о конкурсе и пригласили участвовать в нем.

Answer (score 2):

Не ожидал попасть в победители, но не скрою — это приятно. Sharon и Людмила несомненно заслужили награду. Поздравляю от всей души! И спасибо за удовольствие читать ваши ответы.